# Ranking list RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm pretty new to Android development. Want to ask how to make the first three rank special than others? For example, I will set a gold badge/icon for 1st rank, 2nd rank will be silver and so on?

[image]

Comment: How do you make the 4th and 5th rank look different from each other? please show some code

Comment: I haven't do the code yet, I need some idea how to do it. For normal, I should be query out the result (ORDER BY points from rank 1 to the end). Then, I put all the result to the listview but how do I set the rank with different icon for every rank? Lets say I want display 50 rank. Do I need to create 50 seperate Linearlayout for every rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your list view is complex, so you should use custom adapter for it and custom view, so you would have class which extends `BaseAdapter` and also you have to override `getView()` method in your class it has one `int` parameter which describes position of row and you should write in this method logic which "paints" your first three rows as you want:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);


        switch(position){
            case 0:{
                // change view for first position
            }break;
            case 1:{
                // change view for second position
            }break;
            case 2:{
                // change view for third position
            }break;
            default:{
                // change view for other positions
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```

or use different layouts for each row:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view;


        switch(position){
            case 0:{
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_list_item, parent, false);
            }break;
            case 1:{
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_list_item, parent, false);
            }break;
            case 2:{
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_list_item, parent, false);
            }break;
            default:{
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.general_list_item, parent, false);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thx for the idea and solutions. I think this solve my issue. Will do more research on this. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: you are welcome!